# Does this sentence sound correct. I think it does if the highlighted *it* is a dummy pronoun here

Tags: grammar

The amount of fast twitch fibers in the body has increased.
However, it ain't actually increased
but *it* is converted from slow twitch fibers to fast twitch fibers

Comment: It's not a dummy pronoun because it refers to *the amount of fast twitch fibers*. The weird part here is that "ain't", this discoyrse sounds like an academic writing, so *ain't* which sounds uneducated doesn't fit here.

Comment: Did you make this up? Do you have a source?

Comment: This is not standard English in several ways: **ain't** instead of **isn't**; "amount of fibers" (we'd use "number of" with countable nouns); and the use of the verb-to-be instead of **hasn't** as the auxiliary with **increased**; and a neither-fish-nor-fowl usage of **it** (which isn't quite existential and isn't quite anaphoric).  *The number of fast-twitch fibers in the body has increased. However, there hasn't been an actual increase in the total number of fibers; slow-twitch fibers have been converted to fast-twitch fibers.*

Answer (score 1):

The italicized "it" can be included or omitted. The word "but" has to have parallel structure between the comparisons. With the italicized "it," the comparison is between two independent clauses (The two items being compared could stand alone as sentences). Without it, then two subordinate clauses are being compared. The sentence the way it is now needs a comma since there are two independent clauses:

The amount of fast twitch fibers in the body has increased. However, it ain't actually increased, but it is converted from slow twitch fibers to fast twitch fibers.

Both instances of "it" are pronouns without an antecedent. I would suggest writing the sentence like this:

The amount of fast twitch fibers in the body has increased. However, the total number of fibers hasn't actually increased, but the new fast twitch fibers are converted from slow twitch fibers.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer, but personally, I would write the second part as, "...but the new fast twitch fibers are actually converted slow twitch fibers." Not to make you change it, just providing an alternative for anyone reading.